# postback not raised problem

Tags: asp.net, events, dynamic, user-controls, postback

I have next situation:

- I load dynamic controls during on init, and I do correct initialization.
- I add dynamic control before postback
- I don't add anything later in load
- control is loaded and diplayed correctly
- I press postback and nothing happens

Why I really don't know.. I tried everything. So control IS properly initialised. __EVENTTARGET shows the same path as the UniqueId of linkbutton that is firing it. All controls in tree have viewstate=true. So, I really don't know what this is not working.

Any idea? I am desperate.. I don't know.. if anyone could suggest me, if not solution, then just things I should check would be very good.

Comment: When exactly during the page lifecycle do you add the dynamic control? ("I add dynamic control before postback" isn't quite clear.)

Comment: Do you re-add the dynamically loaded controls during the postback? Can you show some parts of your code?

Comment: Dynamic controls are difficult to get it right.


Refer to this series of articles:

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/10/16/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-3_2900_.aspx

Comment: this is loaded in page init
        private void LoadControl(PlaceHolder holder, string path, string ID)
        {
            UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl(path);
            ctrl.ID = ID;
            LastControlPath = path;
            ctrl.EnableViewState = true;
            holder.Controls.Clear();
            holder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
and this was working .. so i take this data from session.

Comment: Now it doesn't . I don't know.. u see id, everything. before i had similar code and it was working fine.

Comment: <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="SellWizard" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="NavigationSplit">
            <div class="rightpart">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SplitControlLoader" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
   ...........

Comment: this method is never called? why?         protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);
            LoadLastViewControl();

            // viewstate loaded, now we know which control to show.
        }

Comment: solution yogi thank u very much.. that helped. So problem is in page lifecycle and in control recreation. I did my solution by placing viewstate and initaliaziton in LoadViewState method instead of OnInit event.. then everything works fine.(i hope, not that i did all checks but it does look promising).

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem just for this page or do you have other pages on the same site with the same problem?

I am assuming that you have the same problem on all pages.

It could be relate do javascript not being allowed. You could try to add the site to local intranet security are, then refresh the page.

Comment: No i have javascript. postback does happen. Form is submited.

Comment: Just to make sure: You see that the form is submitted when you press the button? (for example an entry in the IIS log)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls have to be added back to the control tree on each postback for the events to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls are not part of their container's viewstate, so setting it to TRUE wouldn't have any effect on the situation and are not evaluated until after the on_init call completes anyways.

I would wrap the logic that is populating these dynamic controls in with a conditional check for a postback `if(!IsPostBack)
{ //Insert logic here }`

If your dynamic controls take input from the user, or need access to their view state, then you would need to move this call to the Page_Load method as this is the point in the page's lifecycle where viewstate is first evaluated.